# how to implement a vectorised version of this code snippet in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, vectorization

I am newbie in MATLAB , and hence find it hard to transition from C-style Matrix implementation to MATLAB's implementation, so for the below code snippet what would be the vectorised MATLAB implementation?

```
g = zeros(size(z));

for i=1:size(z)(1),
for j=1:size(z)(2),
g(i,j)= 1/ (1+exp(-z(i,j)));
end;
end;
```

z could be matrix , scalar or even a vector.
Thanks for your help!.

Comment: Have a look at https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html especially the `Evaluate the expression  $x^2 + y^2$ over the 2-D grid.` example.

Comment: `g = 1 ./ (1 + exp(-z));`. It's as simple as that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
g = zeros(size(z));

g = 1 ./ (1+exp(-z));
```

The key is using the dot `.` before an operation, which makes it element-wise.
So each element is operated on with its corresponding element in other matrices, as opposed to matrix operations being used.

See Docs:

https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/array-vs-matrix-operations.html

Comment: Thanks sir! Got it!